# Variables available when building static sites using jekyll and github pages

Tags: variables, jekyll, github-pages

When building a website using github pages and jekyll, we can use variable like `site.github.repository_name` etc. Where these variables values are furnished by github pages when building the site. But I cannot find a comprehensive list of these variables in either documentation for github pages nor in pages about github pages in jekyll documentation.

I have already checked in

- https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/
- https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/
- https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages-and-jekyll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub Pages use some plugins that are enabled by default and cannot be disabled. One of them is [jekyll-github-metadata](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata).

Which, as stated in the description:

- Propagates the `site.github` namespace with [repository metadata](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/blob/master/docs/site.github.md)
- Sets `site.title` as the repository name, if none is set
- Sets `site.description` as the repository tagline if none is set
- Sets `site.url` as the GitHub Pages domain (cname or user domain), if none is set
- Sets `site.baseurl` as the project name for project pages if none is set

`site.github.repository_name` comes from the repository metadata mentioned above, along with `site.github.wiki_url` and lots of other stuff.

Comment: so is `site.url` something like `https://whatever.github.io/project`? does it have a trailing slash?